# Atlassian Crowd and myBB integration

Tags: atlassian-crowd

Can Atlassian Crowd be used as a single sign on service for  **[myBB](http://www.mybb.com)**?  If so, how can I setup myBB to import users from crowd?

If anyone knows why I have to keep signing in everytime I change menu screens in myBB admin console can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: There are lots of things called "Crowd", and no less than three different projects called "My BB".  Can you clarify, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  We had to modify one of the files to stop myBB from continuously logging out.  Crowd integration was easy to setup by adding myBB as a generic application in the applications tab on Atlassian crowd.